# How to inject viewmodel in compose UI test?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

My composable function

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    myViewModel: MyViewModel,
    navController: NavController
){}
```

My viewodel class

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val myUseCases: MyUseCases
): ViewModel()
```

UI test class for composable

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyScreenKtTest{

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val hiltTestRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    lateinit var navController : TestNavHostController


    @Before
    fun init(){
        hiltTestRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun DemoTestFunction() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current)
            MyScreen(myViewModel = hiltViewModel(),navController = navController)
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("My name").assertIsDisplayed()
    }

}
```

The error is

Cannot create an instance of class MyViewModel

How to inject viewmodel in composable UI test?

Comment: I solved this by creating a test module and inject all dependencies of viewmodel in test class.

Answer (score 0):

You have mention **composeTestRule.setContent{}** inside init() block

```
 @Before
fun init(){
    hiltTestRule.inject()
    
      composeTestRule.setContent {
        navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current)
        myViewModel = composeTestRule.activity.viewModels<MyViewModel>().value

        MyScreen(myViewModel = myViewModel,navController = navController)
    }
}
```

Comment: 'composeTestRule' does not have activity property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyScreenKtTest{

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()
    ...
```

With:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyScreenKtTest{

    @get:Rule(order=0)
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()
    ...
```

And then inside the test:

```
@Test
    fun DemoTestFunction() {
        composeTestRule.activity.setContent {
              navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current)
            MyScreen(navController = navController)
        }
}
```

Comment: This actually gives the following error:
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @ilkeraslan can you share your MainActivity?

Comment: it's just an empty activity which extends to a ComponentActivity, nothing fancy.